# Odd behavior with Ruby defined?

Tags: ruby, yaml, settings, defined

I am a newbie at Ruby and have a question with the defined? keyword.

Here's a snippet of code that I've written to load a yaml file to initialize settings in my Ruby script:

```
# Read settings file
require 'YAML'
settingsFile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "settings.yml").tr('\\', '/')
Settings = YAML.load_file(settingsFile) unless defined? Settings
puts Settings
```

The yaml file looks like this:

```
Hello: World
```

This outputs correctly with:

> {"Hello"=>"world"}

Now if I use a variable instead of a constant to store the settings, such as the following:

```
# Read settings file
require 'YAML'
settingsFile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "settings.yml").tr('\\', '/')
settings = YAML.load_file(settingsFile) unless defined? settings
puts settings
```

settings returns empty.

What gives? Why would using a constant make this work?

Comment: That should be `require 'yaml'`. On case-insensitive filesystems that will work, but on case sensitive ones it will fail.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a quirk in the way Ruby handles trailing `if`/`unless` conditions and how variables come into existence and get "defined".

In the first case the constant is not "defined" until it's assigned a value. The only way to create a constant is to say:

```
CONSTANT = :value
```

Variables behave differently and some would argue a lot more *strangely*. They come into existence if they're used anywhere in a scope, even in blocks of code that get skipped by logical conditions.

In the case of your line of the form:

```
variable = :value unless defined?(variable)
```

The `variable` gets "defined" since it exists on the very line that's being executed, it's going to be conditionally assigned to. For that to happen it must be a local variable.

If you rework it like this:

```
unless defined?(variable)
  variable = :value
end
```

Then the behaviour goes away, the assignment proceeds because the variable was not defined prior to that line.

What's strange is this:

```
if defined?(variable)
  variable = :value
end
```

Now obviously it's not defined, it doesn't get assigned, but then this happens:

```
defined?(variable)
# => "local-variable"
```

Now it's defined anyway because Ruby's certain it's a variable. It doesn't have a value yet, it's `nil`, but it's "defined" as far as Ruby's concerned.

It gets even stranger:

```
defined?(variable)
# => false
if (false)
  variable = :value
end
defined?(variable)
# => "local-variable"
```

Where that block of code didn't even run, it *can't* even run, and yet, behold, `variable` is now defined. From that assignment line on forward that variable *exists* as far as Ruby is concerned.

Since you're doing an attempted assignment and `defined?` on the same line the variable exists and your assignment won't happen. It's like a tiny paradox.

Comment: Thanks for that thorough explanation. I would never have even realize this knowing what I know with other languages.

Comment: Yeah, variable scope in Ruby can be really odd. Largely this comes from the fact that they don't need to be declared in advance (e.g. `let x = y` or `int x = y`) and they look identical in terms of syntax to method calls (`x` vs. `x` instead of `$x` vs `x()`)